# How to avoid warning message of "'=': truncation of constant value"?

Tags: c++

I have a bit vector here mostly for academic value. It's flexible for 8, 16, 32, 64, etc. In this case, the underlying array is a 32 bit pointer. Each cell contains 32 bits that can individually set and clear.

```
Bitvector<unsigned long int> b(32);
```

I fill in each 32-bit cell to 1 for all bits.

```
bool setAll()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    { 
        if (m_intSize == 32)
            m_array[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        else if (m_intSize == 64)
            m_array[i] = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
        else if (m_intSize == 16)
            m_array[i] = 0xFFFF;
        else if (m_intSize == 8)
            m_array[i] = 0xFF;
        else 
            return false; 
    }

    return true;
}
```

As anyone can guess, a 32-bit dynamic array pointer can't point to 64-bit, so I get this truncation error on m_array[i] = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

```
warning C4309: '=': truncation of constant value
```

Is there a way to get rid of this warning? Is there some kind of option you can do like -1 * sizeof(T) or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the normal way to do this, assuming an unsigned value, is:

```
void setAll()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
       m_array[i] = -1;
}
```

Unsigned integers in C++ are defined to *wrap around*, so this will always give you the maximum possible value for whatever `m_array[i]` is on that platform.

Alternatively you could `#include <limits>` and use `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`, but that's not quite as cool.